# Wrap Text in LaTeX

Tags: tables, wrap

Hi !
my problem is that I have this code (link below) in LaTeX and as you can see the last column of the table is too wide. I want to wrap the text in 2 lines so I can shorten the width of the table. I limited the width of the column but it damaged other parts of the table.

LaTeX files:
http://www31.zippyshare.com/v/oFbiRLVO/file.html
OR
http://majidok.dl1.rapidpars.com/6679/11763955/450gcauu562/Table%25203.rar

I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome! Please post your code here. Copy as text, paste, select and use the `{}` button or ctrl+k. Questions should be self-contained and not rely on external links, so they remain useful to future users. Moreover, many people will be reluctant to download archives etc. from untrusted sources and/or just won't be bothered to follow links in order to see if they can help you. That is, you'll stand a better chance of getting help, as well as making your question more generally useful, by posting your code here.

Comment: I won't follow such a link, please post the code (shortened to a suitable length) here.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Is there any reason for such apparently erratic and imperceptible colour changes which make the code over-verbose? The colours do not even correspond to the values in cells.

Answer (score 1):

If we change line 40 to

```
\raisebox{\height}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Average change from 20s to 80s}}
```

then it looks like this :

[image]